# Cumulative probability of 2 independent events

Tags: probability, distributions

I’m trying to find the cumulative probability of 2 independent events (at least I think its cumulative probability).

I will miss work on rainy days (event 1) where my car won’t start (event 2). 
The probability that my car won’t start on any given day is 20%.
The probability of rain on any given day in a month is 10 in 30 (33.3%). 
The two events are independent of each other.

The probability that my car won’t start on a rainy day is 0.2 * 0.33 = .067
In a 30 day month I would expect to miss work 0.67 * 30 = 2.0 days (rounded)

But how can I find the probability of missing 1 days, 2 days, 3 days … all 30 days etc. during a 30 day month?

Comment: You have started out correctly. Now think of an event 3 - which is the event that you miss work (i.e. that both events 1 and 2 occur). Forget about events 1 and 2, and concentrate only on event 3 which has probability 0.067 as you stated. Each day, you either miss work or not with probability 0.067...Now think of coin tossing probability calculations you may have already done...

Comment: Thank you for the response. When I think about coin tossing, I think about a formula that looks something like (1/2)^x, where x equals the number of tosses, but this assumes that I only toss the coin x number of times.        I think of this more like dice. If I toss a 6 sided die 30 times, what is the probability of rolling a six once, twice, three times...30 times etc.   I apologize, but I'm a little rusty on my statistics.